# php create DateTime from timestamped returned by IntlDateFormatter

Tags: php, datetime, format, intl

i'm trying to find a convenient way to convert localized date inputs to a standard dateTime object. 
Having english input, it's really easy but unfortunately DateTime doesn't support internationalization, so I guess I'll have to use IntlDateFormatter.

So i've been trying to pass results in between the two and get strange results:

```
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US',
    \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    \IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
$formatter->setPattern("dd MMMM Y");
$timestamp = $formatter->parse("08 February 2012");
```

returns

```
1324767600
```

When I pass that to DateTime

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$formatted = $dateTime->format("d F Y");
```

I get

```
25 December 2011
```

So what am I doing wrong here, or is there maybe a much easier way to do what i want to achieve?

thanks

Comment: You should always know what the input is.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question. i've specified a case where the input is very clearly defined

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your pattern is not coherent with what you want to do.

According to the [ICU documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime), `MMM` expects a three-letter-month. To chose a bigger representation, use `MMMM`.